# Problem of Scottish Book

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

Does anyone know if the problem 50 to Banach written in The Scottish Book is resolved? The problem is:

> Prove that the integral of denjoy is a Baire functional in the space M ( that is to say, in the space of measurable functions)

Thanks

Comment: Why the [theorem-provers] tag?

Comment: Is true that it is not a theorem but is a result what is not prove. Do you can say something more interesting than it? Thank you.

Comment: From the tag-wiki for [theorem-provers]: "Theorem prover (proof assistant) is a software which allows to check steps of formal proof. Such programs often contain an interactive proof editor, which makes writing a formal proof easier. Some known theorem provers: Mizar, Coq, Isabelle."

Comment: (And no, I do not know the status of problem 50.)

Comment: The [MathSciNet review](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=934228) by H. Becker of Kechris's contribution to the Proceedings of the ICM 1986, *[The complexity of antidifferentiation, Denjoy totalization, and hyperarithmetic reals](http://ada00.math.uni-bielefeld.de/ICM/ICM1986.1/Main/icm1986.1.0307.0313.ocr.pdf)* ends with *"This paper seems to be related to a question of Banach which appeared as Problem 50 in The Scottish book [...]. It may even be a solution of that problem. The reviewer has been unable to figure out exactly what that problem means."*